# How to set up an image of a site in LinkedIn profile?

Tags: metadata, linkedin-api

I am trying to add my portfolio website as a link on Summary section and it links just fine but the thumbnail image is just a random image from my site. Is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Check **Improve content sharing with Open Graph** in [here](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin)

Add meta property="og:image" and the image to be displayed while sharing your portfolio website to LinkedIn and other social media sites.

More about open graphs [here](http://ogp.me/)